# Error The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: widget.auth.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) { 
      // showing Error in this part(The body might complete normally, causing 
      // 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', 
      // is a potentially non-nullable type. Also showing
      // type '_AsBroadcastStream<User?>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<User>?')

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              User? user = snapshot.Data;
              if (_user == null) {
                return LoginScreen(
                  onSignIn: _updateUser,
                  auth: widget.auth,
                );
              }
              return Home(
                onSignOut: () => _updateUser(null!),
                auth: widget.auth,
              );
            }
          },
        );
      }
```

showing Error in this part:

> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the builder needs to return a widget in all situations. It doesn't do that when `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active)` is not true. So you could do this for example

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<User>(
    stream: widget.auth.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      // showing Error in this part(The body might complete normally, causing
      // 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget',
      // is a potentially non-nullable type. Also showing
      // type '_AsBroadcastStream<User?>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<User>?')

      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        User? user = snapshot.Data;
        if (_user == null) {
          return LoginScreen(
            onSignIn: _updateUser,
            auth: widget.auth,
          );
        }
        return Home(
          onSignOut: () => _updateUser(null!),
          auth: widget.auth,
        );
      }
      return SizedBox(); //you need to return some widget here. this is an example
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Nice. you may want to use `CircularProgressIndicator()` instead of `SizedBox()`.

Comment: Thank You sir for Solving this